# как подключить скрипт к сообществу вк? на python

Tags: python

написал небольшого бота на python,теперь нужно каким-то образом подключить его к сообществу вк.
подскажите каким образом)) если можно подробнее.

Comment: Используйте токен сообщества для бота. То, как бот будет поддерживать постоянную работу - решаете вы.

Comment: Токен можно получить в настройках сообщества